# Database.Persist and `lastUpdate` field

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

As far as I know `Database.Persist` don't deal for any auto-updated field ([Yesod Book Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent)).

But exists one special case on it is relevant (at least for me :P) it is `lastUpdate :: UTCTime` field (I love it and I used widely to know data changes).

Also, this update must to be performed at database level (if not, all servers should be perfectly synchronized [*it's hard and weak*] and record updates should be done inside transaction to include in it the `getTime` system call [*inefficient*]).

My current workaround is create (**manually**) a trigger.

Do you know a better way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like that's important to you, relying on a database's `now()` is safest, as that will consistently use the beginning of the transaction as the return value.If you compute the time in the application itself, you'll have to be very careful to pass the same value around everywhere.

You can look into Haskell's esqueleto library to compose sql in such a way that you'd always have an additional `set` call for your `lastUpdate` column. I don't think it currently exposes the sql `now()` function, so you might want to add it yourself to the lib.

Comment: I think `now()` is only valid inside trigger (or sql embedded) since "The default attribute has absolutely no impact on the Haskell code itself" (eg. entity constructors require values for `created` and `lastUpdate` fields) I think the only real solution is to add triggers at `persistent` migrating level (instead manually) but I don't know how.